# Why is this chicken getting sores on here face?

Tags: injury, chickens

We noticed that one of our chickens is getting pretty nasty looking sores on her face (photos below). Does anyone have any idea what could be causing them? For background: we live in the high desert, where it's been cool lately. So not a lot of insect population.  We also have three other female chickens, but they are much smaller, two polish and one silky.  I think they are too small to do this to a larger chicken.  Also, they've all lived together for a year and we've never observed this issue. I'm not sure if there's any further relevant information that could help to understand what could be causing the sores. We will take her to the vet once we can get an appointment, but in the mean time, it would be great if someone had some useful information.  Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your other chickens has done this,injuries around the head/neck and tail are almost always caused by other chckens.

injuries at the belly or chest can be caused by rats,chickens(and may other birds are unable to see in the dark)this makes them an easy target for other animals.

I have seen this types of injuries on our own chickens many times,we had 50 chickens at a time for close to 30 years.

Your only option might be to separate the chicken from the rest of them.

Comment: In a group of same-sized chickens I would have expected bald spots at the neck and back where the other ones pecked her, but since she only lives with smaller hens, they probably target the face because they cannot reach the back as easily.